# Avoiding code duplication in websites

Tags: html

I will create a webpage that has a sidebar, and the sidebar will have links to other pages and stuff. The way I am coding, for each link on the sidebar, I have another HTML document. The sidebar links just link to another .html file, which contains the website template/layout whatever you want to call it. So I have an index.html that is the home page, then an about.html, etc. And for each of the html documents, the file contains the code for the layout of the entire website (the sidebar, footer, etc). So between the different links that the sidebar links to, the only difference is the content. So if I want to change the layout of my webpage (the color of the sidebar, for example) I will have to go to each HTML document and change it.

So my question is how are people supposed to go about doing this? I don't think I am doing it correctly. Are you just supposed to have one file that contains the template?

Comment: Please use a descriptive title for your question.

Comment: "with sidebars, divs, some css, etc" - you need **more** CSS :-) Cascadable style sheets allow you to make _massive_ changes to layout, colors and so forth, in one central location.

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moneydev,

What you are looking for is a templating system. If you want to stick with pure HTML you'll have to use external tools to help you because it doesn't have a built-in way to template. Dreamweaver has the capacity to allow you to define areas inside your webpages to indicate they are the same area, to be maintained "as one" throughout your entire website.

The way that works though, is actually pretty low-tech. What it does is search through ALL the files in your Dreamweaver managed website and "search and replace" the section when you edit it from the "master location" which is determined when you set it up in the first place.

Ali Hamze suggests using 'includes' inside PHP projects. That is the common approach for PHP, but I'm biased and much prefer ASP.NET's answer to templating. It is a combination of ".master" (pages) and ".ascx" (controls) that allow you to template and re-use these in nested fashion. It is FAR beyond a simple "search and replace" (as done by Dreamweaver with your HTML) but would require you learn a new development environment.

So what it boils down to, is you can stick with HTML which will be far simpler and allow you to focus on learning HTML/CSS and JavaScript. This is great to build a foundation for development... however, to really move into the "big leagues" I'd recommend choosing an IDE.

As a long time Windows guy, I do favor ASP.NET via Microsoft Visual Studio and Microsoft SQL for the databases. That said, I'm the kind of person that can drink Coca-Cola, and still like Pepsi. If you'd like to look into PHP or Java, those are great options too. Here are places I'd go if I wanted a FREE and powerful IDE to get my web development life off to a healthy start:

ASP.NET (Microsoft Visual Studio) --- Read about 'Master pages' and 'Control files' for templating
http://www.microsoft.com/express
(I prefer Microsoft SQL (Express Edition is fine) for databases, though you CAN use mySQL if you like)

PHP (Eclipse IDE for PHP) --- Look into 'includes' for templating
http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt

Java (Eclipse IDE for Java) --- Look into 'http://www.stringtemplate.org/' for templating
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr2
(for the above, if you want a database behind the scenes, check out mySQL)
http://www.mysql.com/

FYI: You might find Microsoft's IDE the least intimidating, though PHP isn't too tough to start with. Java may be challenging if you're new.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [PHP](http://php.net) which will allow you to have a file for the header, another for the sidebar and all other stuff which will be the same on all pages. Then you just [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it in the index.php, about.php.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all your styling in an external CSS stylesheet that is referenced in the head of each html page. Then, you can change the styling in one place. This addresses your example of changing the sidebar color.

If you want to keep a consistent html structure for the sidebar on each page, use php. You would create a file called sidebar.php, and use the `include` method to import the same code into each page. If you want to change it later, edit the single sidebar.php file, and all the others will import the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers to that. The most typical is to use a server-side language that *preprocesses* the HTML. This way you can have a general layout file and separate "views". The views only contain the unique content for each page, the layout contains the essentially unchanging wrapper around it. You can then piece those two together as needed without code duplication.

Learn any server-side language you find interesting, from PHP over Ruby to Python or *.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, for me, is a little server side scripting in a language called PHP.  I create header.php, footer.php, and in your case, I'd create a sidebar.php file as well.

So what's PHP?  It's a scripting language and it's extremely useful.  In your case, it's not really that important, but you can do a *super* handy thing with it - include other files.  Your web server has to have PHP installed and running.  You can also run it on your local PC with a great free tool called Xampp.

So when I got started, I'd create a file called index.php.  In that file, I'd start with a head section as usual.  Include your CSS (You are making CSS files, right?  It's way better than a style section - you can re-use that same stylesheet and it has a few other benefits as well.) and set up any scripts if you are using them. In the body, you'll use a special PHP tag to run a little bit of PHP code:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

That will "include" the file called header.php.  Whatever you put in there is now part of this document when you load it.  It can be plain PHP, HTML, or even plain text.  Use it to set up your header.  At the bottom of the page where your footer goes, use a little more PHP:

```
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

In footer.php, you guessed it - put your footer code.  Then close the body tag and the html tag.  You can also include your sidebar with this same technique.  I suggest any HTML tags you open in the included file also close in the same file.  It will make it easier to manage the individual pieces of your pages.

This is about the simplest thing you can do with PHP, but it's a really handy technique for making reusable parts of a site.  You'll save tons of time and effort once you master it.